# For in Javascript does not work for events from a JSON

Tags: javascript, json

I recive this part of a JSON:

```
"out": {
    "gen": [
      {
        "title": "Options",
        "opt": [
          {
            "label": "Button1",
          },
          {
            "label": "Button2",
          },
```

And, I try to put as a button, every labale value with this, because I need to send the value of those buttons to a function. The `send()` function:

```
var options = '';
var p;
for(let i=0;i<q.out.gen[0].opt.length;i++) {
    var opt=options +=`<input id='element' type='button' value="${q.out.gen[0].opt[i].label}">`;

                   $(document).ready(function(){
                    $("#element").click(function(){
                      p = ($(this).attr("value"));
                      send(p);
                    });
                  });
                  }

          var resp = rch(
            `<b>${opt}<br>`, 
            );
```

The code puts the buttons I need but at the time of executing it, only the first label of the first button works, and sends twice

```
"Button1" "Button1"
```

And the second button that is "Button2" not working.

How can i fix this? That each label is a button and at the moment of pressing it send the value of each button that would be `"Button1"` and `"Button2".` Thanks

Comment: I fixed it. Thanks

Comment: "id" values should be unique across a given page.

Comment: If you've fixed it, either add an answer, or delete the question. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Can you try switching `id='element' to class='element'?`
Might be a fix with `$(document).on("click", ".element", function() {...}` as well if still not working after change using event delegation..

Comment: And then `$(document).on("click", ".element", function() {...}` can be outside the loop

Comment: @jwatts1980 but when I press it, it sends it once, and then sends it twice, and then 3. It's already outside the For but I don't know why it does that